# How to share filters between parent and child

Tags: vue.js

//main js

```
window.chat = new Vue({
    el: '#Chat',
    components: {
        chat: Vue.extend(require('./../components/chat/component.vue'))
    },
    filters: {
        emoji: function(content){
            return content;
        }
    }
})
```

// chat script.js

```
module.exports = {
    components: {
        message: Vue.extend(require('./../components/message/component.vue'))
    }
}
```

// message template

```
<span>{{{ message.text | emoji }}}</span>
```

This stuff gives me

```
app-1.0.4.js:12304 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: emoji (found in component: <message>)
```

I tried $root.emoji and $root.filters.emoji just for the sake of trying but it didn't work.

So how can I make this work. I really want to keep the filter in main.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a mixin (https://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html):

mixins/filter-emoji.js:

```
module.exports = {
    filters: {
        emoji: function(content){
            return content;
        }
    }
 }
```

main.js

```
window.chat = new Vue({
    el: '#Chat',
    mixins: [
        require('./../components/chat/component.vue')
    ],
    components: {
        chat: Vue.extend(require('./../components/chat/component.vue'))
    },
});
```

message/component.vue:

```
module.export = {
    mixins: [
        require('./../components/chat/component.vue')
    ]
}
```

This is one of the ways to share filters accross certain components. If you need it more often, you could even register it globally (see documentation https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/custom-filter.html):

```
Vue.filter('emoji', function(content){
    return content;
});
```

Comment: thanks ! i feel so bad for forgetting about the .filter